# Potentially dangerous request is loading the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, validate-request, .net-security

I hosted an application in ASP.NET 4.0 webforms.

When I am browsing hostname/DressDetail.aspx?`<script>alert(313)</script>`&category=1&code=76
It is showing an error message like:
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (="alert(313)

But I am expecting same error message as above when I am browsing hostname/DressDetail.aspx?`<script>alert(313)</script>=1`&category=1&code=76

But it loads the page. But it should not be. The only difference is an extra =1 in the latter url.

Comment: Which framework is this, Web Forms? MVC? Core?

Comment: It is in webforms

Comment: We need to see your web.config

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I just tried it and the page loads, but the alert doesn't fire. There's also nothing in Event Logs (Windows Logs), but there is a warning-log without the -1.

Comment: Should probably ask on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Greg  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097151" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxUrlLength="1024" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" enableVersionHeader="false" />

Comment: @wazz Thanks and I have posted the same in  security.stackexchange.com